# How to run javascript code if date criteria is met

Tags: javascript, html, criteria

I am trying to figure out a way to run a piece of javascript code if a date criteria is met:

For example:

- Do not run the code if the date is between `June 6th, 2014 5PM CST` and `June 16th, 2014 5PM CST`.

Or I guess the opposite may be more precise.

- Run code between `June 6th, 2014 5PM CST` and June 16th, 2014 5PM`AND`June 20th, 2014 5PM CST`and`June 25th, 2014 5PM`.

Any ideas or examples?

Comment: First of all, which time do you wish to verify? User computer time (not recommended), or Server Time (recommended)?

Comment: Where does the input comes from, a form input field like datepicker , from other given source or when 'a computer or server has this time'? Maybe that helps to prevent such general answers as below.

Comment: if ( new Date(2014,5,6,5) > new Date() < new Date(2014,5,16,5)  || new Date(2014,5,20,5) > new Date() < new Date(2014,5,25,5) ){ ... }

Comment: @dandavis Since when does `if (x > y < z)` "properly" work in JS?

Comment: I guess this would be server time but I would still want it in EST zone instead of the server time zone.

Comment: Actually, did some further research and it looks like you cant get server time just using JS so computer time will have to do if there is no other JS option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply put the code within an if statement?

```
//create current Date
var curDate = new Date();
//This date represents the upper limit of the interval
var upperDate = new Date('June 20, 2014 05:00 PM');
//This date represents the lower limit of the interval
var lowerDate = new Date('June 6, 2015 05:00 PM');
//Timezone settings on the client should be correct for this comparison to work
if(lowerDate > curDate || upperDate < curDate) {
//Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward approach would be to run a polling function.

```
setInterval(poll, 1000); //interval is in milliseconds, so this will run poll() function every second.

function poll(){
  if (your_date_conditions){
     a_funciton_you_want_to_run(); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want code to execute based on a certain criteria...that sounds like an if statement to me.

I'm not sure what else you could mean.

Comment: I don't understand how someone can down vote using an If statement for conditional logic...